# Problem with apache2 rewrite rule (mod_rewrite)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm having problems with mod_rewrite and apache2. I want to do this:

> domain.com/{username}/{everything_else} to domain.com/users/{username}/{everything_else}

{username} is everithing before first "/" and {everything_else} is everything after the first "/" simbol (may contain other "/", the exact number vary).

I tried unsuccessfully this:

> RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /users/$1/$2 [L,NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /users/$1/$2 [L,NC]

this works only if {everything_else} doesn't contain other slashes

> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*) users/$1/$2 [L,NC]

Would it be possible to make something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.*)$ /users/$1/$2
```

The ? in the first capturing group means: capture as less characters as possible (so until the first /). The rest is captured as-is.

Comment: Thank You for this advice! I tried this and I get this error message: "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace". Maybe the problem is, because of infinity loop, because folder "users" match the rule and after first redirect start looping again.. Is there a way to exclude requests that start with /users/* from looping?